# Windows Kernel Mode Driver Project Template doesn't appear in Visual Studio Project Template menu after downloading WDK

Tags: visual-studio, wdk

Recently I've menaged to develop Windows Kernel Mode Driver so I started reading about that. I've read I need to download WDK. I use Visual Studio 2017 Community so I've downloaded WDK (for Windows 10) version 1709 (in default folder if it matters). When I try to create new project there should appear new templates for developing drivers but they don't.

(From what I've read I've deduced I only need to download the WDK and it's enough, am I right? It's described like that on MSDN)

So my question is: what am I supposed to do to the Kernel Mode Driver Project Template appear in Project Templates menu? I've really tried to google my problem and I did research but I haven't found anything usefull. I know it looks like very silly question and I'm so sorry if it does but I really don't know what to do, I tried many things like redownloading the WDK or downloading other version and so on but nothing helped. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: install "C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\Vsix\WDK.vsix" to get the templates

Comment: Thanka for reply, but once I try to open WDK.vsix I'm getting error "The extension manifest is invalid.". I've searched and found that it may happen when Visual Studio version isn't valid, e.g. it's 2015 instead of 2017, but I have Visual Studio 2017 and it's valid version. Have you any idea what causes this error? Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try the VSIX from my system: https://www.dropbox.com/s/8lku8du7p19utdw/WDK.vsix?dl=0

Comment: I'm getting the same error even with your WDK.vsix... Thank you for reply

Comment: repair VS2017 and the WDK via the installers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use Visual Studio 2015 and Visual Studio 2017 installed at the same time, I've seen this cause problems. Neither have two versions of  WDK installed at the same time if you happened to have done this.

1. Uninstall all versions of Visual Studio on your machine.
2. Install Visual Studio 2017.
3. Install the latest version of Windows Driver Kit (WDK) for Visual Studio 2017.
4. Try again and see if the template shows up.

Did the installation of WDK throw any errors last time? Is the folders for WDK present under the Windows Kit area? We sort of need more details if possible, otherwise we'll just be guessing into oblivion for the next 1000 roman years.

Comment: Thank you very much for reply and so sorry for too few details. Instalation of WDK doesn't throw any errors, folders for WDK present under the Windows Kit area. I'll uninstall all versions of Visual Studio and download Visual Studio 2017 as you mentioned and I'll probably reply tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you very much both @PspSetProcessPpmPolicy and @magicandre1981! Everything is working after reinstall!

Comment: That is great to hear! I am glad to have helped you. I cannot deny, I have had similar issues like this before... Especially while setting up a kernel debugging environment with Visual Studio. It can be quite frustrating sometimes when things don't work right. :)