# Visual studio 2015 and WDK 10 on windows 7 os

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, visual-studio-2015, wdk

Can I install WDK(windows driver kit) 10 on windows 7 and work using VS2015?I already installed visual studio 2015 first then installed WDK 10. But couldn't find windows driver in installed section.It has under visual C++ template the following options - General,Win32,MFC,Test,CLr,ATL,Windows etc.Can you specify what OS support which version of WDK.

Thanking you in advance.Any help appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows Kernel Mode Driver Project Template doesn't appear in Visual Studio Project Template menu after downloading WDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48037652/windows-kernel-mode-driver-project-template-doesnt-appear-in-visual-studio-proj)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where is WDF template after installing wdk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43698680/where-is-wdf-template-after-installing-wdk)

Comment: Win10 WDK until Build 15063 (1703) can be used with VS2015, starting with Build 16299 (1709) WDK only supports VS2017.